# GUIDE4YOU - how to add a dynamic layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, guide4you

The guys from **guide4you** did a great job making this lib opensource!!

I've succeeded in having a working demo **guide4you** sample.

How adjustable is the lib? 
For instance how can I add layers with GeoJSON instead of KML.
Can the layers be added dynamically (with own javascript) instead of predefined?

Take this as example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

To be more specific: how can that example work together with **guide4you** ?

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a GeoJSON layer in guide4you you can just specify the type "GeoJSON" in the layerconfig.

`{
      "id": "3",
      "type": "GeoJSON",
      "source": {
        "url": "path/to/geojson"
      }
    }`

See also https://github.com/KlausBenndorf/guide4you/blob/master/conf/full/layers.commented.json for some examples

If you like to add a layer on the fly with javascript you can use this api function:

`map.get('api').addFeatureLayer({
      "id": "3",
      "type": "GeoJSON",
      "source": {
        "url": "path/to/geojson"
      },
      "visible": true
    })`

the possible options are the same as in the layer config.

If you like to add only new features you can create a layer with type "Intern" and add the features with openlayers functionalities. The source of a feature layer is a subclass of [ol.source.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html).
In the example below I am assuming that geojsonObject is of the same kind as in the geojson example of openlayers.

    `var layer = map.get('api').addFeatureLayer({
      "id": "3",
      "type": "Intern",
      "source": {
        "features": []
      },
      "visible": true
    });
    layer.getSource().addFeatures((new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject));`

And last but not least you can use a simplified api to define features inside a layerConfig object like this:

`{
      "id": "3",
      "type": "Intern",
      "source": {
        "features": [{
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Some feature",
          "description: "Some description",
          "style": "#defaultStyle",
          "geometryWKT": "... any wkt string here ..."
        },{
          "geometryWKT": "... any wkt string here ..."
        }]
      }
    }`

this can be used either in a layerConfig file or in the addFeatureLayer api method.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks for the fast answer!! When I place the code in index.html inside the script block I get "ReferenceError: map is not defined"

Comment: You can use createG4U('#g4u-map').then(function (map) { ... here map is defined ... })

Comment: I tried this myself, it does not work because the map is not ready at this point. This should work:  createG4U('#g4u-map').then(function (map) {
          map.asSoonAs('ready', true, function () { ... here ... }) })